# Pass command line arguments to NodeJS script from NPM script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a main script (**publish-all.js**) from which I want to invoke the *npm publish* script of an Angular project, which also has a sub-script (**publish.js** that does general stuff (creating folders, copying files, moving folders...) after `ng build`.

I need to pass some environment variables to that second script.
I am using **shelljs** to run unix-like commands.

I tried using:

```sh
npm run publish -- VERSION=${productVersion} DESTDIR=${productDestinationPath}
```

From **publish-all.js** where *productVersion* and *productDestinationPath* are constants declared above that line, and which invokes the following script from the package.json:

```json
"publish": "ng build --prod && node ./scripts/publish.js"
```

But the actual command line I get is

```sh
ng build --prod && node ./scripts/publish.js "VERSION=value" "DESTDIR=value"
```

Finally, in my **publish.js** script I tried getting those variables the following way:

```js
let version = process.env.VERSION;
let destinationPath = process.env.DESTDIR;
```

But I get `undefined` values.

What am I doing wrong? Is the a better way of doing all this?
Should I maybe use **process.argv** instead??

I am using this strategy because it is what I were told to do, but I would like to know if there is a less confusing way.ç

---

**EDIT 2021-07-13**

I tried using export (with shelljs, since I am in Windows and using powershell) but I am getting an exception.
I have the following code in **publish-all.js** now:

```js
shelljs.exec(`export VERSION=${productVersion}`);
shelljs.exec(`export DESTDIR=${productDestinationPath}`);
shelljs.exec('npm run publish');
```

And in the **publish.js** script from the ANGULAR project:

```js
version = process.env.VERSION;
destinationPath = process.env.DESTDIR;
```

Though it does not get to **publish.js**. It gets stuck in the `shelljs.exec('npm run publish')`, with the following exception:

[image: Exception screenshot, which says: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'project folder/node.exe']

I had to hide the project folder because of privacy policies, but it is a subfolder inside the folder where I am executing **publish-all.js**.

Comment: If you're trying to set environment variables they go _first_, currently you're passing them to what would be `process.argv`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So I should use instead `VERSION=${productVersion} DESTDIR=${productDestinationPath} npm run publish`? Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environmental variables go BEFORE the command. So, instead of passing them after you can add them BEFORE:

```
VERSION=${productVersion} DESTDIR=${productDestinationPath} npm run publish
```

Or,
You can export the variables first then run the script:

```
export VERSION=${productVersion}
export DESTDIR=${productDestinationPath}
npm run publish
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I updated the question because I got stuck again. If you could look at it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: feel free to ask a different question cause the old question and new question has very less common.

Comment: to accept this answer press the gray tick below the arrows